# AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values' django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am trying to get data from django server and get this error.

```
Internal Server Error: /data/site-info/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 53, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hco/PycharmProjects/tool/linyit/data/views.py", line 17, in site_info
    Response(serializer.data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 674, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 239, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 614, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 459, in to_representation
    fields = self._readable_fields
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 353, in _readable_fields
    field for field in self.fields.values()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'
```

my_app/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^site-info/$', site_info, name='site_info'),
]
```

my_app/models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class SiteInfo(models.Model):
    site_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    # managed = False
    db_table = 'site_info'
```

data/views:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import SiteInfo
from .serializers import SiteInfoSerializer


# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def site_info(request):
"""
    List all sites
"""
    if request.method == 'GET':
       sites = SiteInfo.objects.using('teldata').all()
       serializer = SiteInfoSerializer(sites, many=True)
       Response(serializer.data)
```

my_app/serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import SiteInfo


class SiteInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = SiteInfo
    fields = ('site_id', 'site_name', 'latitude', 'longitude')
```

what could be the problem? thanks

Comment: you have `return` as prefix in `Response(serializer.data)` on your view, right?

Comment: yeah you are right, i don't know how i can't see it. sorry for that silly misatake :(

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your serializer needs to use a nested `Meta` class to declare `model` and `fields` (you were declaring them as normal attributes of the class instead of nesting them):

```
class SiteInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteInfo
        fields = ('site_id', 'site_name', 'latitude', 'longitude')
```

Comment: thanks it solved my problem :) i did some other small mistakes but it was the main problem i guess

Comment: When I see these Meta classes, I tend to think of forms in Django.  It's my weird way of reminding me to put it in a meta class.

Comment: same issue here... had the fields below the Meta but indentation was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

by adding (class Meta) in serializers.py the error can get solved as per my error which i were getting.

[the image which shows code of serializers.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rUCz.png)

Comment: Please don't post a picture of code. Post the code itself.